# Zooming Camera Preview is also Resizing the Control

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to scale/zoom the camera preview around the center point, but I don't want the control itself to "grow" which is what is currently happening.  How can I do this?

```
<CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5"  Width="400" Height="300"  >
  <CaptureElement.RenderTransform >
    <ScaleTransform   x:Name="zoom"  />
  </CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
</CaptureElement>
```

..and then when the zoom slider moves I have:
    zoom.ScaleX = sliderZoom.Value;
    zoom.ScaleY = sliderZoom.Value;

When I move the slider the image does scale, but the whole CaptureElement is growing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `RenderTransform`, you could try using a `ScrollViewer` instead:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="PreviewScroll" ZoomMode="Enabled" Width="400" Height="300">
  <CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
  </CaptureElement>
</ScrollViewer>
```

That will give you zooming automatically. Also, the scrollviewer will keep its size, but the child control (the `CaptureElement`) will grow inside the scrollviewer.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping to somehow restrict the image size so that when I save the photo to a file it will reflect what they actually saw, but if I can't figure that out I'll do the ScrollViewer.

Comment: You could use the scrollviewer data Width/Height and ExtentWidth/ExtentHeight to figure out the sizes, and HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset to figure out the position of the viewable area. And then use that to crop and save the image.

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I'm trying to do now, but while ScaleTransform works great in the preview the Horizontal/Vertical Offsets remain 0 when I zoom.  It seems like there should be a way to "ask" the scrollviewer for that upper left coordinate of the image, but I haven't found that yet.